# Analysing the derivatives of a sketched curve

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I have the following graph and want to know:

Are these statements correct and if not why?

- question A: $f'(-2) > 0$
- question B: $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$ and $f''(0) \neq 0 $
- question C: there are two intervals where the curvage of the graph is curved right
- question D: $f''(-1) < 0$
- question E: $f(6) > f(-4)$
- question F: $f'(-4) > f'(6)$
- question G: $f'(6) = 0$ and $f''(6) >0$

[image: graph]

I am new to this materia (had just some lessons) and need simple explainations.

Currently my solutions are:

- question A: dont know
- question B: correct and correct and dont know
- question C: is correct between $-4$ to $0$ and $0$ to $6$
- question D: dont know
- question E: correct, -2.5 > -3.9
- question F:
- qeustion G:

Comment: 1) What do you mean by curvage? It's not a word I've ever heard to describe a curve. 2) When you choose tags, there is a short description of the tag right there. Pick appropriate ones (this is not functional analysis).

Comment: What are your answers? And then maybe we can help you correct the wrong ones.

Comment: This is a great post for those looking for how this site *does not* work. 1) Please TeX up your question, 2) Do not ask so many questions in one post, 3) Show us some of your work, etc.

Comment: @Johanna He's analyzing a function, so to the average person his question relates to functional analysis (analysis of a function).

Comment: @Johanna if f''(x) < 0 it is curved right, and if f''(x) > 0 it is curved left, the German word for is called right-curved or left-curved

Comment: @ErdincAy Thanks :) I've only ever heard concave or convex to describe that.

Comment: @Shahar, I learnt it but can not use it, I have to less experience, because of the exam tomorrow, there were many other topics to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- question A: $f'(-2) > 0$

  Yes, it is correct. It looks like there is an instantaneous slope of around $+1$.
- question B: $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$ and $f''(0) \neq 0 $

  No, it is not correct because the statement $f''(0) \neq 0$ is false. (The statements $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ are true, by the way.) From the graph, you will see that concavity changes. The graph is concave down for the interval $(-\infty,0)$, then it is concave up for the interval $(0,2)$.
- question C: there are two intervals where the curvage of the graph is curved right

  Yes, it is correct. There are two intervals where $f$ is concave down: intervals $(-4,0)$ and $(2,5)$.
- question D: $f''(-1) < 0$

  Yes, it is correct. The graph is concave down on the interval $(-4,0)$, as I stated above in my response to question B. Since $x=-1$ falls in the interval $(-4,0)$, the statement $f''(x)<0$ is true.
- question E: $f(6) > f(-4)$

  Yes, it is correct, because as you said, $f(6)=-2.5$ and $f(-4)=-3.9$, and $-2.5 > -3.9$.
- question F: $f'(-4) > f'(6)$

  No, it is not correct. Like [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110199/differential-calculus-curves-and-gradients-f-4-f6/1110203#1110203), $f(-4)=f(6)=0$. So it cannot be true that $f(-4) > f(6)$.
- question G: $f'(6) = 0$ and $f''(6) >0$

  Yes, it is correct. The graph has a horizontal tangent line at $x=6$; so $f'(6)=0$. The graph is also concave up on the interval $(5,\infty)$. Since $x=6$ falls in this interval, $f''(6)>0$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean in Question C; please clarify. Specifically, what is "curvrage"?

Comment: question E, shouldnt it be -2.5 > -3.9, and therefore true

Comment: question C, means there are two intervals where the curve is concave down, is it true?

Comment: Oops, yeah you're right. I'll fix that.

Comment: thx, bro, you saved my life, now i want to learn more about this topic

Comment: can you see my comment on question C, is C correct?

Comment: For question C: Yes, that's true. There are two intervals where $f$ is concave down: intervals $(-4,0)$ and $(2,5)$